# Testing the existence of a method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some existing JS backwards compatible. I need to override a method if it does not exist, otherwise just return the existing method.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
this.grid.getDataSource = function(){
    if (getDataSource == undefined)
        return getStore();
    else
        return getDataSource();
}
```

However it keeps returning an error on the "if" line:

> getDataSource is undefined

What is the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work without throwing an error.

```
if (typeof getDataSource != "function")
```

Comment: I'd prefer testing `(typeof getDataSource == "function")`, as testing for it not being `undefined` (cf. the else clause) doesn't reveal it actually *represents* a function; the variable might as well refer to a string or other primitive.

Comment: @Marcel of course, you're right. Removing the second variation.

Comment: Ah, I just saw you [always get capitalization wrong](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14873/english-german-translation). ;)

Answer (score 1):

you might need to wrap it in a typeof<strike>() function</strike>

```
this.grid.getDataSource = function(){
if (typeof getDataSource == undefined)
    return getStore();
    else return getDataSource();
}
```

Comment: FYI, *typeof* is not a function - it's an operator. You don't need the parens (see [Pekka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552383/testing-the-existence-of-a-method/3552392#3552392)).  I learned that the hard way here on SO :-)

Comment: it may be an operator, but I use parenthesis a lot of the time just to make it more readable, especially if you are doing "typeof(asd.getName)" or something

Answer (score 1):

<strike>this.grid.getDataSource = getDataSource || getStore;</strike>

Comment: This will still throw an error if *getDataSource* hasn't been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice resourse, which should answer to your question. It's a pretty simple function.

http://phpjs.org/functions/method_exists:471

Comment: OMG, what's this? Using a custom function for *one* simple comparison isn't very efficient...