# Overriding a Javascript method only if it does not exist

Tags: javascript, methods, overriding, parent

My goal here is to override a method if it isn't found, otherwise use the original method (for backwards compatibility of a library I can't alter).

This is what I have so far, but am still struggling with:

```
this.grid.getDataSource = function(){
        if (typeof this.grid.getDataSource.getDataSource == "undefined")
            return this.grid.getDataSource.getStore();
            else return this.grid.getDataSource.getDataSource();
    }
```

I want to have getDatasource() check if it exists, if not, call getStore(). If it does exist, just use the original getDatasource(). I know this breaks because I haven't figured out how to reference the parent 'this' scope. When I work around that issue I get into a recursive loop as it keeps trying to override itself. If you have a better way of doing this please let me know!

Comment: Why did you ask this again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552383/testing-the-existence-of-a-method

Comment: Same code, different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should do what you want.

```
this.grid.getDataSource = 
    this.grid.getDataSource.getDataSource || this.grid.getDataSource.getStore;
```

this statement will try to find something that evaluates truish from left to right. when it finds that thing, it will use it as the value for the assignment. in this case if `getDataSource` is undefined it'll evaluate as false, and `getStore` will be checked. `getStore` exists so it'll evaluate to (roughly) true, and so the function reference will be assigned to `this.grid.getDataSource.getDataSource`;

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that getDataSource() will not throw an exception, you can try

```
this.grid.getDataSource.getDataSource = function(){
    try {
       return this.getDataSource();
    }
    catch(ex) {
       return this.getStore();
    }
};
```

or you can just change

```
 if (typeof this.getDataSource == "undefined")
```

to

```
if (typeof this.getDataSource != "function")
```

UPDATE:
Does this work?:

```
this.grid.getDataSource = function(){
    if (typeof this.getDataSource != "function")
        return this.getStore();
    else 
        return this.getDataSource();
}
```

Comment: How do I reference the parent 'this' scope from within the function body?

Comment: you can't... just remove this.grid.getDataSource from everywhere in the function body (check my post again)

Comment: Here is my new code based on your example. getDatasource isn't defined in the function body. Am I misunderstanding something?
this.grid.getDataSource = function(){
 try {
  getDataSource();
 }
 catch(ex) {
  getStore();
 }
}

Comment: This is failing with a 'Too much recursion' error. It seems to be recursively trying to redefine getDataSource over and over again.

Comment: you're right... have you tried lincolnk's solution. It seems more elegant.